# JScrollPane which resizes depending on the available space but only up to a maximum size

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane embedded in a GridBagLayout.
Most the time the content of the JScrollPane is smaller than the available space.
In this case I want the JScrollPane be exact the size it needs to be.

For example, if I have 10 Lines of text with a total height of 100px the JScrollPane should be 100px, without any scroll bars.
(This doesn't has to be dynamic it would be enought if I could set the maximum size, the content will not change.)

Only if I resize the JFrame and the available space becomes smaller than the content of the JScrollPane I want the JScrollPane to shrink and the scrollbars to appear.

I've tried to use the GridBagConstraints.fill parameter.
That works for the resizing to any size but it also always fills the whole space (what it is supposed to do if use the fill parameter , I think).

If I just set the size of the JScrollPane via setPreferedSize() wihtout the fill parameter and the Frame becomes smaller than this preferedSize the scrollPane immediately shrinks to a tiny chunk (as I read I shouldn't use the setPreferedSize method anyway(?)).

I've also tried the BoxLayout with the prefered and minimum size but if the available space becomes smaller than the prefered size the JScollPane instantly uses it's minimum size.

To sum up: I need a JScrollPane which resizes depending on the available space but only up to a maximum size.

What layout and settings do I have to use to get the desired result?

I am struggling with this problem since hours :(

**EDIT:**

Here a few screenshots:

The JScrollPane on the left side below Radio 1 and 2.

The frame in the normal size, the JScrollPane only uses the space it needs:
[image: Normal size]

If I make it larger the JScrollPane shall not change (works):
[image: Big Size]

But if I make the Frame smaller than the JScrollpane, the components get messed up:
[image: Small Size as-is]

What I want it to look like:
[image: small size to-be]

Comment: use a LayoutManager that supports the fine-grained control. Not sure if GridBag allows it - anyway, you would be better of with one of the major third party managers, like MigLayout (my current favourite), FormLayout or DesignGridBag

Comment: I would like to do it with the standard layout managers but If there is no other way I could use 3rd party managers. (I think there is a way - somehow :D)